# Covariance between estimated y and observed y(in simple linear regression)

Tags: linear-regression

I wonder what is $Cov(y,\hat{y})$ the Covariance between estimated $\hat{y}$ and observed value $y$, in the situation of simple linear regression.
Some Youtube tutor said it's 'O', but i can't agree with that.

You know, the linear regression model is like this.
$$y_i = \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_i + e_i $$
$$\hat{y_i}=\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x_i$$

How I approached is like this.

For a certain number 'i',
$$Cov(y_i,\hat{y_i})$$
$$=Cov(\hat{y_i}+e_i, \hat{y_i})$$
$$=Cov(\hat{y_i}, \hat{y_i}) + Cov(e_i, \hat{y_i})$$
$$=Var(\hat{y_i}) + 0$$
so $Cov(y_i,\hat{y_i})$ becomes $Var(\hat{y_i})$. But with this, I can't make an important derivation about the variance of $e$. And I think I'm wrong, but I can't find the clue that my derivation is wrong.
Thank you for help

**All derivation of The variance of the prediction error
**

$$e_i = y_i - \hat{y_i}$$
$$var(y_i - \hat{y_i}) = var(v_i) + var(\hat{y_i}) - Cov(v_i, var(\hat{y_i})) $$
here, we all know what $var(v_i)$ and $var(\hat{y_i})$ is. And the derivation of $Cov(v_i, var(\hat{y_i}))$ is above.